# Determine which INNER JOINS or WHERE clauses restrict MySQL 5.5 row updates

Tags: mysql

I have an update statement which I thought should update some records, but it doesn't.  I'm using MySQL 5.5.46.

How can I determine which `INNER JOIN` or `WHERE` clauses are preventing it?

Answer (score 0):

Very easy method is to change UPDATE into SELECT, and see the results of your SELECT-query. When you are satisfied with your INNER JOIN modifications by getting the correct records that you want to update, just change SELECT back into UPDATE to realize your record-update. Success.

Comment: To what advantage?  Maybe I can agree with changing it into a SELECT statement and using EXPLAIN.  I thought I could use EXPLAIN directly with an UPDATE statement, but can't seem to do so?

Comment: The advantage by using SELECT compared to UPDATE is that now you can test your query as much as you like, until you found the query that really provides the result that you require. If you start testing this with UPDATE, then in the meantime half of your record-set will be updated and might be corrupted. And you can use explain, but just alter your sql-query and test with SELECT until you get the the records you expected, and then move to UPDATE again. By testing you will learn more about how SQL works and why some of the records are showing up with WHERE and INNER JOIN.